# JsonPatchDocument is null after migration to .Net Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net, .net-core-3.0, json-patch

I have a AspNetCore-WebApi-Project with several patch-operations, which worked fine with Core 2.2. After migration to Core 3 the `[FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<T>` is null. My Get/Post-Methods are still functioning as expected.

This is one part of my Startup:

```
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options
                    .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                    .UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"), 
                        opt => opt.UseNodaTime()));

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My-API", Version = "v1" });
    });
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

This is my Action:

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Patch(Guid id, 
                            [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<MyViewModel> patchDocument)
{
    await this.service.HandlePatchAsync(id, patchDocument);
    return NoContent();
}
```

This is the body-content:

```
[   
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/name",
        "value": "New Name" 
    },
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/country",
        "value": "Germany" 
    }
]
```

Does anyone have an idea what is goung wrong here?

Comment: Did you migrate 2.2 to 3.0 as per the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) ? I tested it and it worked well . Could you share a demo that can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: I didn´t get the right package. It was not clear to me, that I had install a new package, beside the call of AddNewtonsoftJson(). in startup. But thank you anyway for looking at this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I struggle with a similar issue. I was going to get rid of `Newtonsoft` at all, but in that case the patch with `JsonPatchDocument` was not working.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support you should:

1. Add a package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`
2. Change code in the startup adding MVC to `services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();`

You did the second step, but what about the first?
This helped me.

Unfortunatelly, I do not know how to make JsonPatchDocument work without `.AddNewtonsoftJson()`

Comment: Thank you very much! Installing the package solved my issue

Comment: There won´t be a possibility to get rid of newtonsoft, because JsonPatchDocument relies on newtonsoft internally. Maybe they replace this package as well in future releases.

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem with [FromBody] in a post action setting the model to null.After installing the package it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

As of .NET 5, it seems that JsonPatchDocument depends on the JsonSerializers from NewtonsoftJson. That is to say, in the source code for JsonPatchDocument, there is

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonPatchDocumentConverter))]
public class JsonPatchDocument : IJsonPatchDocument
{
```

where the JsonConverter attribute is from the Newtonsoft Json Namespace.

I think I am able to define a JsonConverter so that it works in System.Text.Json.
Something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.Operations;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class JsonPatchDocumentConverter : JsonConverter<JsonPatchDocument>
    {
        public override JsonPatchDocument Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Operation>>(ref reader, options);
            return new JsonPatchDocument(result, new DefaultContractResolver());
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, JsonPatchDocument value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And then in Startup.cs,

```
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonPatchDocumentConverter());
        });
```

... OR alternatively, inherit JsonPatchDocument and define the attribute there

```
namespace MyProject        
{
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(JsonPatchDocumentConverter))]
    public class JsonPatchDocument : Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.JsonPatchDocument
    {

    }
}
```

and then use the JsonPatchDocument subclass so that the JsonConverter from the attribute is picked up by System.Text.Json

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Patch(Guid id, 
                            [FromBody] MyProject.JsonPatchDocument patchDocument)
{
```