# JsonPatchDocument<T> parm is null on entering API using a flurl client

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor-server-side, flurl, json-patch

I'm using Flurl to call my .net core 3.1 API, but the JsonPatchDocument parm is null on entering the API. I can call this same API with HttpClient, and it works fine, but I'm trying to stick with flurl since my other get/put/delete API calls all work using flurl.

Here's the calling code (from a Blazor web client):

```
+------------+
| Web Client |      
+------------+
public async Task<BoatDto> UpdateBoatPartialAsync(Guid clubId, Guid boatId, BoatForUpdateDto boatForUpdateDto){
    BoatDto boatDtoFromApi = null;

    var patchDoc = new JsonPatchDocument<BoatForUpdateDto>()
        .Replace(o => o.Name, boatForUpdateDto.Name)
        .Replace(o => o.Description, boatForUpdateDto.Description);

    var serializedPatchDoc = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDoc);

    var uri = $"https://localhost:44383/clubs/{clubId.ToString()}/boats/{boatId}";
    var url = uri.WithHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    var json = new StringContent(serializedPatchDoc);
    json.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json-patch+json");
    boatDtoFromApi = await url.PatchJsonAsync(json).ReceiveJson<BoatDto>();
    return boatDtoFromApi;
}
```

Here is the API:

```
+-----+
| API |     
+-----+     
[ApiController]
[Route("clubs/{clubId}/boats")]
public class BoatsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ClubRepo _clubRepo;
    private readonly BoatRepo _boatRepo;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public BoatsController(ClubRepo clubRepo, BoatRepo boatRepo, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _clubRepo = clubRepo ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clubRepo));
        _boatRepo = boatRepo ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(boatRepo));
        _mapper = mapper ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapper));
    }

    [HttpPatch]
    [Route("{boatId}")]
    public ActionResult UpsertBoatPartial(Guid clubId, Guid boatId, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<BoatForUpdateDto> boatPatchDocDto)
    {
        //boatPatchDocDto is null
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to change your API endpoint like below:

`[HttpPatch]
    [Route("{boatId}")]
    public ActionResult UpsertBoatPartial([FromRoute]Guid boatId, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<BoatForUpdateDto> boatPatchDocDto)
    {
        //boatPatchDocDto is null
        return Ok();
    }`

Comment: Also, have a look to this link, it might be related to the .Net version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58542164/jsonpatchdocument-is-null-after-migration-to-net-core-3?rq=1

Comment: Hi @Nazim, I assume you intended to put the [FromRoute] attribute on both guids (not just one), but alas, the parm still is null. [FromRoute]Guid clubId, [FromRoute]Guid boatId

Comment: Sorry, I missed one parameter. I managed to replicate on my side, if you properly register  formatter on the Startup file on your API side it works. I managed to get data sent from Web Client to API. Could you please setup as it is mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-3.1#jsonpatch-addnewtonsoftjson-and-systemtextjson

Comment: Hmm. That didn't work, but it looks as tho Todd's answer was correct for my issue in that i was double serializing my patchDoc. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use methods like `PatchJsonAsync`, Flurl is doing the serializing for you, using Newtonsoft.Json under the hood). You don't need either of these steps:

```
var serializedPatchDoc = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDoc);
...
var json = new StringContent(serializedPatchDoc);
```

That's basically going to double-serialize, which probably explains why the API isn't interpreting it right on the back end. Just send the `patchDoc` directly. Most of your client-side example can be reduced to this:

```
boatDtoFromApi = await uri
    .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json-patch+json")
    .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    .PatchJsonAsync(patchDoc) //edited
    .ReceiveJson<BoatDto>();
```